1997 Bravada car will not hold a charge
My car started out periodically having to get a jump to now everyday it will not hold a charge. I've cleaned the post on the battery and had it check it was good. Then i checked again said sounding like slow charge I first notice the flashing light saying check gages on the panel then while charging my phone up it had burnt 2 phone chargers I also have a Amp / stero hooked up as well help please and thank you

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How old is the battery?
